# Hard linking directory structure somewhere else

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I have one directory where files appear in. I want to run a script regulary that finds all files in that directory that have only one link to them, and hard link them in another directory. However, I want the directory structure in the second directory to be created to match the first.

> find /srcdir/ -links 1 -exec ln {} /dstdir/ \;

Does hardlink all files, but does not create the directories I need.

If a directory contains only files that have already multiple links, that directory does not need to be created in the destination.

Comment: Your question states that you have "one directory where files appear in". I take it what you mean is you have one directory with various subdirectories that files appear in?

Comment: Yes, indeed. Files can also appear in that directory directly, but there can also be new subdirectories where files appear in.

Answer (score 5):

Since hard links are rather cheap, you might make them like : (this will make hard link of all files, and create directory's as in the source)

```
cp -al source dest
```

Then you can remove the hardlinks that are in some other location on your file system. (if double hard links are a issue) Using the slightly adapted find command you posted.

Comment: Just to explain a little further... `a` is for `archive`, this keeps the same permissions/ownerships on all the files/directories. `l` creates `hard links` instead of duplicating the data.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question correctly and you have one directory (`sourcedir`) with various sub directories and the linked files can be either in `/sourcedir/` or in `/sourcedir/foo` or `/sourcedir/bar` etc, then this should do what you need:

```
find /sourcedir/ -links 1  | sed 's/.sourcedir.//' | while read n; do \
  mkdir -p /destdir/`dirname "$n"`; ln /sourcedir/"$n" /destdir/"$n"; \
done
```

It uses `dirname` to get the sub directory of each file and `mkdir -p` to create the directory structure in the destination directory.